# HelpWanted: Plot line of points after a moving marker leaflet js with react

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

Hope everyone doing great in this begin of a week;

So as the title describes the issue i need this maker that moves when i get the Geolocation data from outside API this marker starts moving as i get the data and leaving behind it a line like in the screen below.
i did this solution i found somewhere but it won't give the expected result as get the last 10 Positions from the API then get them in an array and map over them in each point plot a marker it wasn't that much good.

Thanks in advance for you help. Have a nice day. :) Keep smiling.

this is what i got : 
[image]

this is what i want to get : 
[image]

Comment: You need to implement [leaflet routing machine](https://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/) to your app but be aware that the api has restrictions in the number of requests.

Comment: Hi there i really appreciate your answer. i saw this on google but i thought it's for free isn't ?

Answer (score 0):

i'm sure that someone going to look everywhere about this topic on the net i got you.
so you need to use Polyline of Leaflet-react which takes as argument an array of positions then it will trace a line somehow like in the second picture good luck.
Have hope.